# Ionic and Angular get request going into an infinite execution

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am very new to Angular and Ionic framework. I am trying to get some data from a mysql back end. The php returns the right data because I have tested it. The problem, is, when I run the code in the emulator it never stops running. I can confirm this by inspecting the browser and going to console. Below are my simple functions.

In my **service.ts** file, I have a simple function that gets to a php URL.

```
 getLikes(id){
       return this.http.get(this.LIKECOMMENTHANDLER);
    }
```

In my **component.module.ts** file, I used the above function and simply log the response

```
getLikesCount(id){
    //console.log("my id "+id);
    this.restaurantInfo.getLikes(id).subscribe(
      (response)=> {console.log(response)},
      (error) => console.log(error)
    );
  }
```

I called the above function in my **template.html** file as follows.

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let restaurant of restaurants" 
    (click)="navigateToRestaurantDetailsPage('RestaurantDetailsPage', 
    restaurant)">
    //display restaurant information here then
    <ion-col>
        <button ion-button icon-left clear small>
           <ion-icon name="thumbs-up"></ion-icon>
           <div>{‌{getLikesCount(restaurant.id)}}</div>
        </button>
     </ion-col>
</ion-card>
```

The code keeps running and never stops and it creates a memory leak.

Comment: return something in getLikesCount

Comment: Gaurav that is exactly what I was doing but still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

In type script, the view will update automatically. so it is making infinite looping.

To fix that:

In component.module.ts, create a global variable:

```
likeCount:number = 0;
```

In component.module.ts constructor use like this:

```
this.likeCount = getLikesCount(restaurant.id);
```

In template.html use like this:

```
<div>{{likeCount}}</div>
```

Comment: I don't have access to a single Restaurant object in the componnent.module.ts instead it is an array of restaurants that I have access to. So I can't use restaurant.id in the function at that point.